# RichTextBox сохранение в формате rtf в базу данных

Tags: c#, sqlite, rtf, sql

помогите решить проблему. пытаюсь сделать кнопку которая берет форматированный текст из richtextbox и записывает его в sqlite ну или в любую бд?

для упрощения примера вывел одну свою рабочую кнопку.

Код C#

```
private void button3_Click(objectsender, EventArgs e) 
{ 
mydb = new sqliteclass();  
sSql = @"insert into birthday (FIO,bdate,gretinyear)"; 
sSql +=" values('Толстой Лев Николаевич','1928-08-28',0);"; 
if(mydb.iExecuteNonQuery(sPath, sSql, 1) == 0)  
{   
Text = "Ошибка записи!";  
} 
mydb = null;  
Text = "Запись 2 добавлена!";   
}
```

как записать вместо 'Толстой Лев Николаевич' содержимое RichTextBox в формате rtf 
и потом достать в таком же форматированном виде.

Пробовал добавлять так

```
sSql += " values('" + richTextBox1.Rtf+ "','1928-08-28',0);";
```

Но не могу достать его в таком же форматированном виде. 
достаю вот так:

```
private void button10_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    mydb = new sqliteclass();
    sSql = "select * from  birthday";
    DataRow[] datarows = mydb.drExecute(sPath, sSql);
    if (datarows == null)
    {
        Text = "Ошибка чтения!";
        mydb = null;
        return;
    }
   // Text = "";
    foreach (DataRow dr in datarows)
    {
        //Text += dr["id"].ToString().Trim() + "  " + dr["FIO"].ToString().Trim()
        //      + "  " + dr["bdate"].ToString().Trim() + " ";

        richTextBox1.Rtf += dr["FIO"].ToString().Trim();

        richTextBox1.Text += dr["FIO"].ToString().Trim();
        listBox2.Text += dr["FIO"].ToString().Trim();
    }
    mydb = null;
}
```

укажите мою ошибку пожалуйста.

Забыл добавить. создание самой таблицы:

```
   private void button8_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        mydb = new sqliteclass();
        sSql = @"CREATE TABLE if not exists [birthday]([id] INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT,[FIO] TEXT NOT NULL,[bdate] datetime NOT NULL,[gretinyear] INTEGER DEFAULT 0);";
        //Пыьаемся создать таблицу
        mydb.iExecuteNonQuery(sPath, sSql, 0);
        sSql = @"insert into birthday (FIO,bdate,gretinyear) values('Александр Сергеевич Пушкин','1799-06-06',0);";
        //Проверка работы
        if (mydb.iExecuteNonQuery(sPath, sSql, 1) == 0)
        {
            Text = "Ошибка проверки таблицы на запись, таблица или не создана или не прошла запись тестовой строки!";
            mydb = null;
            return;
        }
        sSql = "select * from  birthday";
        DataRow[] datarows = mydb.drExecute(sPath, sSql);
        if (datarows == null)
        {
            Text = "Ошибка проверки таблицы на чтение!";
            mydb = null;
            return;
        }
        Text = "";
        foreach (DataRow dr in datarows)
        {
            Text += dr["id"].ToString().Trim() + dr["FIO"].ToString().Trim() + dr["bdate"].ToString().Trim() + " ";
        }

        sSql = "delete from  birthday";
        if (mydb.iExecuteNonQuery(sPath, sSql, 1) == 0)
        {
            Text = "Ошибка проверки таблицы на удаление записи!";
            mydb = null;
            return;
        }
        Text = "Таблица создана!";
        mydb = null;
        return;
    }
```

Comment: @Shinma, Согласно правилам форума, вопросы не должны сводиться к работе за автора. Пожалуйста, уточните, что вы сделали сами и что не получилось.

Comment: Вы хотите записать именно форматированный текст, или просто текст?

Comment: именно форматированный текст. поэтому я пытаюсь работать с rtf и reachtextbox

Comment: Если доступ к базе данных происходит в `OnClick`, у вас гораздо бóльшие проблемы.

Comment: все полный облом. при стриме в биты у меня перестанет работать поиск нужного слова во всех записях. а без стрима в биты я не смогу сохранить форматированный текст. буду думать дальше.

Comment: к сожалению конструкция портала hashcode не дает возможности мне писать последние сообщения внизу, как у всех нормальных русских людей принято. так же не дает возможности отвечать на комментарии, да и ответить на свой же вопрос ПРАВИЛЬНЫМ кодом система не дает. в общем вопрос исчерпан. портал кривой.

Answer (score 1):

Крайне рекомендую использовать параметризированные запросы, это Поможет упростить чтение запроса, и не придётся думать об экранировании спец символов.

Единственное, что для каждого языка запросов параметры могут обзываться по-разному.

Посмотрите помощь у вашего класса выполняющего запрос sqliteclass().

Запрос должен быть примерно такого вида:

```
Sqliteclass.commandtext = "insert into birthday (FIO,bdate,gretinyear) values(@fio,@bdate,@year);"
Sqliteclass.parameters.add("@fio", "пупкин");
Sqliteclass.parameters.add("@bdate", "2000.10.11");
Sqliteclass.parameters.add("@year", 0);
Sqliteclass.iExecutenoquery();
```

Ps: прошу прощения за оформление, на планшете вообще проблема писать ответы и комментарии, вообще не предназначена морда лица сайта для мобильных устройств :-(

Comment: извините я не понял как мне это поможет. но у меня вроде назрело другое решение

        private void button14_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            MemoryStream memoryStream = new MemoryStream();
            Char[] T0 = richTextBox1.Rtf.ToCharArray();

            memoryStream.Write(Encoding.Unicode.GetBytes(T0),0,T0.Length);
            data = memoryStream.ToArray();
        }

осталось разобраться как биты data сохранить в базу и потом оттуда достать и вывести в richtextbox. увидел что через memoryStream в sqlite сохраняют картинки, и решил сохранит так же текст. ищу как.

Comment: да на мозиле сайт очень коряво работает с текстом и я не могу вставить class sqliteclass

Comment: class sqliteclass
    {
        //Конструктор
        public sqliteclass()
        {

        }
        #region iExecuteNonQuery
        public int iExecuteNonQuery(string FileData, string sSql, int where)
        {
            int n = 0;
            try
            {
                using (SQLiteConnection con = new SQLiteConnection())
                {
                    if (where == 0)
                    {
                        con.ConnectionString = @"Data Source=" + FileData + ";New=True;Version=3";
                    }

Comment: else
                    {
                        con.ConnectionString = @"Data Source=" + FileData + ";New=False;Version=3";
                    }
                    con.Open();
                    using (SQLiteCommand sqlCommand = con.CreateCommand())
                    {
                        sqlCommand.CommandText = sSql;
                        n = sqlCommand.ExecuteNonQuery();
                    }
                    con.Close();
                }
            }

Comment: catch (Exception ex)
            {
                n = 0;
            }
            return n;
        }
        #endregion
        #region drExecute
        public DataRow[] drExecute(string FileData, string sSql)
        {
            DataRow[] datarows = null;

Comment: SQLiteDataAdapter dataadapter = null;
            DataSet dataset = new DataSet();
            DataTable datatable = new DataTable();
            try
            {
                using (SQLiteConnection con = new SQLiteConnection())
                {
                    con.ConnectionString = @"Data Source=" + FileData + ";New=False;Version=3";
                    con.Open();
                    using (SQLiteCommand sqlCommand = con.CreateCommand())

Comment: {
                        dataadapter = new SQLiteDataAdapter(sSql, con);
                        dataset.Reset();
                        dataadapter.Fill(dataset);
                        datatable = dataset.Tables[0];
                        datarows = datatable.Select();

                    }
                    con.Close();
                }
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {

                datarows = null;
            }
            return datarows;

        }
        #endregion

Comment: @shinma, так и отправляйте свой массив байт через 
    Sqliteclass.parameters.add("@fio", bytes);

Comment: @pincher1519, лучше уж строчку отправлять. Зачем себе лишнюю работу создавать

Comment: @donil, Какую лишнюю работу?

Comment: @pincher1519, перевод в байты и обратно

Answer (score 0):

Перед сохранением в базу переведите rtf в base64, тогда ничего экранировать не придется.